# How to display Feedburner subscription count as plain text via a shortcode in post/page editor of my Wordpress blog?

Tags: shortcode, subscription, feedburner

I would like to create a shortcode like `[feedcount]` in my wordpress blog to display Feedburner subscription count as plain text on some of my posts/pages. Moreover, I'd prefer in the case that the Feedburner API is not unavailable, the shortcode shows "many other" instead of the count.
How can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a shortcode, or how to access the feedburner API?

Comment: @TomJNowell: Want to know how to access the Feedburner API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TomJNowell implies, you would achieve this by integrating the Feedburner API with the [WordPress Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) in a [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). However, the [Feedburner APIs have been shutdown since October 20, 2012](http://www.nevillehobson.com/2012/09/09/prepare-for-goodbye-feedburner-in-october-2012/) and this is no longer possible. As [Google continues to deprecate support for Feedburner](http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/28/the-feedburner-deathwatch-continues-google-kills-adsense-for-feeds/), your best course of action is to pursue alternatives to the service.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a php script for it, is not a wordpress plugin , but is good point to start :)

```
$fb_id = "Mashable"; // here your id account
$fb_uri = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/~fc/";
$app_uri = "http://feedcounttext.appspot.com/?uri=";
$count_uri = $app_uri.$fb_uri.$fb_id;
$fb_count = fopen($count_uri, "r");
echo fgets($fb_count);
fclose($fb_count);
```

source code here : https://github.com/salsan/FeedCountText

Require you active FeedCount on your account of FeedBurner

Example

Mashable

http://feedcounttext.appspot.com/FeedContText.php?uri=http://feeds.feedburner.com/~fc/Mashable

Comment: Would be nice if you post the code directly inside your answer were everybody can find it without leaving the post :-)

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information (even if it's just some bits of code) that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem _here on the site_. Thank you.